# Java Mail API read message body problem

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I have a question about receiving emails from a smtp server.
So I must get the messages from the server and get their body but I have a problem with this.
I tried get the input stream of the message and read it all but it read really the all content of the message. 
So my question is : How to read a mail message body with Java mail api, the title part and the from part?

I search in google but with no success. I'm sorry if the question look stupid but I'm a beginer in Java Mail API.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

you can read just the message body using the getContent method.

`((MimeMessage)message).getContent();`

[this](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/JavaMail/contents.html) is an exceptionally well written resource on JavaMail API

Comment: OK but what I have to do with Multipart messages and with the code which you gave me I don't read only the body. I read and a server information.

Comment: with multi part messages you need to use the class MultiPart in place of MimeMessage, here is an example http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/JavaMail/contents.html#GettingAttachments